# Select Records Using Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to retrieve set of 1000 records from table.. If i select 1 - 1000 in dropdowm means it will show first set of 1000 records.

Then if i select 1001 - 2000 in dropdowm means it will show second set of 1000 records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) LINQ extension methods in order to [paginate your data source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24480/Using-Linq-to-paginate-your-ObjectDataSource).